# How to add another file system in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

I am planning to add a file system say, "My cloud" under `org.apache.hadoop.fs` in Hadoop, something similar to KFS or S3 which are already there under `org.apache.hadoop.fs`. I wanted to ask that say, I write my file system for "My cloud" and add the package under fs but then how do I tell the `core-site.xml` or other configuration files to use "My cloud" file system. Where all do I need to make changes to enable "My cloud" file system become a part of Hadoop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually extremely easy:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.mycloud.impl</name>
    <value>com.yourcompany.yourpackage.MyCloudFileSystem</value>
</property>
```

Now you can refer to files on that filesystem using URLs like `mycloud://authority/path/to/file`, and you'll start to see counters like MYCLOUD_BYTES_WRITTEN.

Comment: isn't it that i would have to include "mycloud" is some lookup table or somewhere (like Hadoop file inside bin which contains the classpath of all HDFS commands) where Hadoop will refer to which filesystem i am referring to and then the control would automatically be transferred to org.apache.hadop.fs.mycloud package ?

Comment: maybe I don't understand your original question.  The property I gave allows you to configure Hadoop to recognize URLs that start with "mycloud://" and automatically refer paths like that to the filesystem implementation you specify.  If you're trying to replace hdfs with something else, you'll need to use the property fs.hdfs.impl instead,  and you'll probably break something (but MapR has accomplished this kind of thing).